# Can't get my URL parameters to match my API call to postgres

Tags: postgresql, api, rest, post, postgrest

I'm using `postgrest` as an API wrapper to my `postgres` db. The api reads my database schema and creates URL using common characters in the address.

I have a function like so = `create function api.dividend(p_stocks text[])`

A general API call:

```
/url?key=val;key2=val2
```

My API call for function `create function api.dividend(p_stocks text[])`:

```
/dividend?p_stocks=AAPL
```

In this case to test things out, I used `AAPL` as the input parameter.
However this is the error I'm getting:

```
function api.dividend(p_stock => text) does not exist
```

As you see the return error is expecting this function, `api.dividend(p_stock => text)` However I tried creating a function using those parameters and I dont think its possible...

I would greatly appreciate some advice or suggestions on what suggestions I should try?

This isn't a schema problem because I've checked if the function is in the appropriate schema.

Here is the full function from postgres, if this helps:

```
create function dividend(p_stocks text[])
    returns table(symbol char, next_dividend_date date, ex_dividend_date date) 
as $$
    select distinct on (symbol) symbol, next_dividend_date, ex_dividend_date
    from api.security_stats 
    where api.security_stats.symbol = any($1)
    order by symbol, date desc 
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: Well you declared `p_stocks` as a text array. Pretty sure the error is coming from just passing a text string to it instead of a text array. Postgres allows function overloading so it is looking for `create function dividend(p_stocks text)` and not finding it and hence the error.

Comment: I understand the error now, I've tried passing it like so previously `/dividend?p_stock=[AAPL]` and still not getting it to work. Is that how you assumed the request would look like?

Comment: No, that would end up as `create function dividend('[AAPL]')` and that is not how you input an array.  That is done as either `'{AAPL}` or `ARRAY['AAPL']`. At some point in the process you have to take the parameters passed in and convert them to one of the forms above before using in the function. I don't use `postgrest`, but I did find this [Using array](https://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/api.html?highlight=array#calling-functions-with-array-parameters)

Comment: Oh wow I was so laser focused on the previous doc segments I completely missed out on the array parameter! Makes total sense, thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue with the help of @Adrian,

`/dividend?p_stocks=%7BAAPL%7D`

This would be the correct URL path for postgrest to use the function/parameter.
`%7b` = `{` , and `%7D` = `}`

Now the URL has the correct array format for my function.